# dplyr return matching columns instead of rows

Tags: r, dplyr

So I have two data frames that look something like this

```
Dataframe1
rsid      NA04015   NA16009   NA19117   NA16213 ...
rs2906360 0         0         1         0       ...
rs6936925 1         0         0         0       ...
rs####### 1         1         0         0       ...
...       ...       ...       ...       ...     ...

Dataframe2
rsid      NA04015   NA19117   ...
rs2906360 0.1332    -1.23     ...
rs4568525 0.47      0.252     ...
rs####### 1.43      0.232     ...
...       ...       ...       ...
```

with dplyr I can easily use `semi_join(Dataframe1, Dataframe2)` to get a version of Dataframe1 that contains only those **rows** with matching `rsids` in Dataframe2. However I want to return a version of dataframe1 that contains only those **columns** with a matching header in dataframe2

so my results would look something like this:

```
Dataframe1_by_column
rsid      NA04015   NA19117   ...
rs2906360 0         1         ...
rs6936925 1         0         ...
rs####### 1         0         ...
...       ...       ...       ...
```

Is there an an easy syntax within dplyr that I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(A="a", B="b", C="c", D="d")
df2 <- data.frame(A="a", D="d")

df1 <- df1 %>%
        select(one_of(names(df2)))
```